# Python Server: Chrome Extension SSL certificate

Tags: python, ssl, google-chrome-extension

Hey I am building a simple API server to handle some functionality for a chrome extension. But I need to the users of my extension/add-on to be logged in and for this I want to make the python api server HTTPS requests only. How would I go about verifying the certificate for my server from the chrome extension? Sorry for this broad ish question, I am very new to web based programming.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything special. Any HTTPS requests made by the Chrome extension will go through the same certificate verification as would any other request made in the browser.

Comment: dont i have to keep something like a public key inside of the chrome extension so it can do the handshake? and if i do how do i tell the browser to use this in the https request???

Comment: No. Your API server's TLS certificate is verified against the browser's certificate store, just like it would be for any other web site.

Comment: yea but doesn't that mean i need to have my certificate verfied by some company in order for it to be added to the certificate store?

Comment: Yes. Or by the non-profit [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), which will issue a certificate for free.